# Application is not loading inside a virtual machine after binding an IP in IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis

I have developed a `dotnet core` application and hosted it in a `IIS` server on Virtual machine (IaaS Azure)

Here is the binding information from `IIS`, where `IP Address` is  *

[image]

While I browse it `http://localhost:8015/index.html`, page loads without any issues.

But, when I change the binding to an `IP Address` in `site binding` setting of the `IIS`, then the page does not load. `BLANK PAGE` appears.

Note: Same application is working fine in my local IIS (hosted in laptop), but does not work in `VM`. So problem seems to be in `VM` ip configurations. Some troubleshooting help appreciated.

Here is `Jexus` troubleshooting report of `binding diagnostics`

```
   System Time: 2/16/2020 3:23:12 AM
   Processor Architecture: AMD64
   OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
   Server Type: IIS
   -----
   This machine has 1 IP addresses to take external traffic.
   * 10.1.0.5.
   -----
   [W3SVC/2]
   ServerComment  : ProcessingService
   ServerAutoStart: True
   ServerState    : Started

   BINDING: http 10.1.0.5:8015:
   This site can take external traffic if,
   * TCP port 8015 must be opened on Windows Firewall (or any other equivalent products).
   * The networking must be properly set up to forward requests from web browsers to 10.1.0.5:8015 on this machine.
   * Web browsers should use URL http://10.1.0.5:8015.
```

Failure tracing enabled: but no logs generated

> %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

**Resolved**

Resolved after adding http://10.1.0.5 to the trusted sites zones in IE!!

Comment: Did you open the port on Azure Portal and Windows Firewall?

Comment: Learn what is a site binding, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background and then run the diagnostics to know which URLs should be used in browsers.

Comment: @LexLi jexus manager says "ASP.NET Core module is not installed as part of IIS." even though I have installed .net core-bundle

Comment: Edit the question to include the report please.

Comment: @CristopherRosales yes, port is open. but I am not trying to access from outside. I am just trying to access from same machine with IP (both private and public ip)

Comment: @LexLi  report updated in question

Comment: RESOLVED!  It's IE trusted zone issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved after adding `http://10.1.0.5` to the `trusted sites zones` in IE!!